# Can't get variable from another file

Tags: php, variables

**Problem**

So, my problem is that I have a file called `login-process.php` which processes login info. And I have another file called `index.php` which is the login / home page. My problem is that I `required 'server/login-process.php'`, but when I try to echo out `$message` (which holds login errors) from `login-process.php`, it doesn't show up. Also, I'm not getting any errors.

**index.php**

```
<!-- HOME PAGE -->

<?php
    include 'server/login-process.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        header("location: admin.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include'templates/head.php'; ?>

        <!-- STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/index/large.css" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="login-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> <!-- END OF NAV -->

        <form class="login-form" action="server/login-process.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username...">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password...">

            <button type="submit" name="login-btn">Login</button>
        </form> <!-- END OF FORM -->

        <?php
            echo "
                <h2>$message</h2>
            ";

         ?>

        <?php include 'templates/scripts.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login-process.php**

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // if input fields are empty
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

        try {

            $loginInfo = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = 1");
            $loginInfo->execute();
            $loginInfo = $loginInfo->fetch();

            // check if username is correct
            if($username == $loginInfo['username']) {

                // if password if correct
                if(password_verify($password, $loginInfo['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;

                    header("location:../admin.php");
                } else {
                    $message = "Your username or password is incorrect";

                    header("location:../index.php");
                }

            } else {
                $message = "Your username or password is incorrect";

                header("location:../index.php");
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    } else if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        $message = "Please add your input values";

        header("location:../index.php");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You redirect to `../index.php` in almost every case, which causes a new request to be sent with all `$_POST` fields cleared, which in turn causes your top-level `if` in `login-process.php` to not be executed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are submitting your form for the specific page `login-process.php` from there if it is everything right you REDIRECT that page to the index page here: `header("location:../index.php");`. The problem is that when you do that you loose all variables created at that time. PHP works in a REQUEST context so, you submit your login it get processed then you redirect it (it is like you have submitted again).

With your current code you can solve it in two ways

1 - either send your form to the `index.php` (`<form class="login-form" method="post">` if you don't add the `action` it will submit to the same page, therefore login.php) as it already require the login_process.php code BUT you will have to remove that redirect (`header("location:../index.php");`) and add some control variables to show the actual index page and not the login form again.

2 - Send the message parameter to the index page so it can receive it and process it like this: `header("location:../index.php?message=$message");` and then you check in the `index.php` if the `$_GET['message']` exists and show it.

If you need more details, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove all instance of:

```
header("location:../index.php");
```

from the file: login-process.php. You keep redirecting, thereby clearing the value of $_POST.